# Matrix Visual duplicate values

Tags: powerbi, report

I have the following two csv files in power bi

Table 1:

Date    Ref Product Quantity    Lot
10/13/2023  SI2502  Tray    26  a1
10/3/2023   SO3214  Nut 36  d2
10/3/2023   SO3214  Screw   20  s6
10/3/2023   SO3214  Sheet   50  s5
10/3/2023   SI2489  Tray    100 a1
9/29/2023   SI6535  Sheet   50  s5
9/29/2023   SO5789  tray    41  a1
9/27/2023   SO3652  Rack    65  r4
9/26/2023   SI5420  Nut 100 d2
9/22/2023   SO3476  Sheet   36  s5
9/22/2023   SO3476  tray    30  a1

Table 2:

Date    prods   order   qty rqty
10/15/2023  Rack    SO5658  54  30
10/3/2023   Nut SO3214  36  64
10/3/2023   Screw   SO3214  20  60
10/3/2023   Sheet   SO3214  50  250
9/29/2023   Sheet   INV 50  300
9/29/2023   tray    SO5789  41  44
9/27/2023   Rack    SO3652  65  84
9/26/2023   Nut INV 100 100
9/22/2023   Sheet   SO3476  36  250
9/22/2023   tray    SO3476  30  85

I want a matrix visual in Power BI as follows:

Date Ref Product Quantity Lot rqty
10/3/2023 SO3214 Nut 36 d2 64
10/3/2023 SO3214 Screw 20 s6 60
10/3/2023 SO3214 Sheet 50 s5 250
9/29/2023 SO5789 tray 41 a1 44
9/27/2023 SO3652 Rack 65 r4 84
9/22/2023 SO3476 Sheet 36 s5 250
9/22/2023 SO3476 tray 30 a1 85

but i am getting the following output

Date prods order qty rqty
10/3/2023 Nut SO3214 36 64
10/3/2023 Nut SO3214 36 60
10/3/2023 Nut SO3214 36 250
10/3/2023 Screw SO3214 20 64
10/3/2023 Screw SO3214 20 60
10/3/2023 Screw SO3214 20 250
10/3/2023 Sheet SO3214 50 64
10/3/2023 Sheet SO3214 50 60
10/3/2023 Sheet SO3214 50 250
9/29/2023 tray SO5789 41 44
9/27/2023 Rack SO3652 65 84
9/22/2023 Sheet SO3476 36 250
9/22/2023 Sheet SO3476 36 85
9/22/2023 tray SO3476 30 85
9/22/2023 tray SO3476 30 250

The rqty column is showing duplicate values.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

i tried creating a relationship between the 2 tables with ref/order as the key

Comment: Please help by providing screen shots or formatting with tables - difficult to read/visualise. Or provide a link to a sample PBIX .

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is using Ref/order as your relationship. You will need to have a unique key in each table which consists of Ref & Product.
Try adding a new column to table 1 `key = [Ref] & "-" & [Product]`
and to table 2 `key = [order] & "-" & [prods]` - and now add a relationship based on these new columns.